# definition of affine plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $k$ be a field. On page 5 of Milne's *Elliptic Curves*, the author defines an algebraic curves to be defined by polynomials $f \in k[x,y]$ **with no repeated irreducible factors in $\overline{k}[x,y]$.**

Why does Milne require $f$ to have no repeated factors? The only reason I can think of is the following: a point on the intersection of two irreducible components is singular, so having repeated irreducible factors would introduce singularies.

But I don't think that's the real reason. Could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He want his curves to be *geometrically reduced*.  Having multiple factors leads to reducible curves, which are then singular at the intersection points of the components.  But having repeated factors leads to *multiple components* (i.e. if you
think scheme-theoretically, then the zero locus of $f^2 = 0$ is a thickening of the
curve $f = 0$).  He wants to avoid this. (Although I don't know what particular later statements he has in mind that motivate this, most likely he wants to be able
to apply the Nullstellensatz and related results, and conclude that $f$ is determined
by its collection of zeroes over $\overline{k}$ --- a statement that would be false
if $f$ was allowed to have multiple factors.)